# Envoyer mkdir issue

Tags: php, linux, laravel, envoyer.io

We connected **Envoyer** to our server without hassle. However if we want to deploy we get the following error:

> mkdir: cannot create directory '/FOLDERNAME': Permission denied

However if we log in to our server ourselves with the same user with SSH we can run mkdir without issue.

Anybody knows what could've caused this issue?

The server runs on **Linux (CentOS)**

Comment: Are you sure you can run the command in the same folder as the Envoyer?

Answer (score 0):

it could come from user permissions.

Are you sure that the user you use to log in with SSH is the same that runs php code (there's often a dedicated user for www in order to limit risks).

You should verify that "PHP user" is authorized to write in this directory (verify user permissions and group permissions).